# First linear regression - interpreting results to guide next step?

Tags: r, regression, linear-model

This is my first time attempting to build a linear regression model and I am not sure what to do next given the results I have.

I have a data set with 24 predictors and 1 response and there are 999 rows in the data set.  The data can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/Whv6tgiv).  I am trying to build a linear regression model with the end goal of being able to predict the response variable.

I decided to log transform the response variable as this resulted in the histogram looking more Normally distributed:
[image: Untransformed response]
[image: Log transformed response]

My first linear regression model was the following:

```
Call:
lm(formula = log(y) ~ ., data = the_data)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.70154 -0.13329  0.01642  0.14626  1.10267 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  5.112026   0.061692  82.863  < 2e-16 ***
v1           0.136381   0.024563   5.552 3.64e-08 ***
v2           0.069991   0.024519   2.855  0.00440 ** 
v3           0.034584   0.024504   1.411  0.15845    
v4           0.031069   0.024562   1.265  0.20620    
v5          -0.078188   0.024556  -3.184  0.00150 ** 
v6          -0.007898   0.024579  -0.321  0.74803    
v7          -0.062695   0.024613  -2.547  0.01101 *  
v8          -0.007664   0.024553  -0.312  0.75501    
v9          -0.019956   0.024558  -0.813  0.41664    
v10          0.025143   0.024561   1.024  0.30623    
v11          0.003946   0.024583   0.161  0.87250    
v12          0.024605   0.024551   1.002  0.31650    
v13         -0.005139   0.024558  -0.209  0.83429    
v14         -0.071931   0.024534  -2.932  0.00345 ** 
v15          0.002112   0.024552   0.086  0.93145    
v16         -0.050584   0.024510  -2.064  0.03930 *  
v17          0.012561   0.024491   0.513  0.60815    
v18         -0.029778   0.024515  -1.215  0.22478    
v19          0.030362   0.024559   1.236  0.21666    
v20         -0.022925   0.024519  -0.935  0.35002    
v21         -0.003210   0.024532  -0.131  0.89591    
v22          0.027668   0.024617   1.124  0.26132    
v23         -0.009467   0.024557  -0.386  0.69993    
v24          0.003332   0.024567   0.136  0.89214    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.223 on 974 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.07552,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.05274 
F-statistic: 3.315 on 24 and 974 DF,  p-value: 1.603e-07
```

The R-squared value (0.076) tells me that this model is not very good, correct?

Looking at the Residuals vs Fitted and Scale-Location plots I think that there is some pattern (upside down parabola).
[image: First model residuals]

So I decided to fit the following model which has first order interactions

```
Call:
lm(formula = log(y) ~ .^2, data = the_data)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.60878 -0.11444  0.00161  0.11522  0.71236 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  4.510425   0.372884  12.096  < 2e-16 ***
v2           0.417113   0.211401   1.973 0.048879 *  
v3           0.554384   0.218996   2.531 0.011577 *  
...   
v12          0.644474   0.219123   2.941 0.003378 ** 
...
v1:v2       -0.501372   0.088464  -5.668 2.12e-08 ***
... 
v1:v5        0.226257   0.091674   2.468 0.013823 *  
...
v1:v12      -0.265495   0.089155  -2.978 0.003003 ** 
...
v1:v16      -0.226053   0.090448  -2.499 0.012674 *  
...
v2:v9        0.175206   0.088957   1.970 0.049285 *  
...
v2:v12      -0.558579   0.087183  -6.407 2.73e-10 ***
...
v2:v16       0.230151   0.088761   2.593 0.009716 ** 
v2:v17      -0.235761   0.087570  -2.692 0.007267 ** 
...
v2:v22       0.219280   0.085991   2.550 0.010984 *  
...
v3:v5       -0.305964   0.087337  -3.503 0.000489 ***
...
v3:v9       -0.303287   0.086619  -3.501 0.000492 ***
...
v4:v5       -0.382494   0.091162  -4.196 3.07e-05 ***
...
v5:v13       0.222259   0.089072   2.495 0.012816 *  
...
v6:v9        0.185673   0.090535   2.051 0.040656 *  
v6:v10       0.216236   0.090258   2.396 0.016849 *  
...
v6:v17       0.255650   0.087794   2.912 0.003707 ** 
...
v6:v22      -0.198706   0.089566  -2.219 0.026838 *  
...
v7:v15      -0.192992   0.089102  -2.166 0.030652 *  
...
v8:v16       0.230660   0.090440   2.550 0.010971 *  
...
v9:v13      -0.190571   0.087136  -2.187 0.029070 *  
...
v9:v23       0.322755   0.088111   3.663 0.000268 ***
...
v12:v17      0.182697   0.090321   2.023 0.043480 *  
...
v12:v22     -0.229433   0.089649  -2.559 0.010700 *  
...
v13:v14      0.232871   0.086159   2.703 0.007043 ** 
...
v14:v15      0.206125   0.089665   2.299 0.021810 *  
...
v15:v16     -0.203924   0.091111  -2.238 0.025523 *  
...   
v22:v23     -0.184572   0.090622  -2.037 0.042055 *  
...
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.2055 on 698 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.4369,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.1949 
F-statistic: 1.805 on 300 and 698 DF,  p-value: 1.863e-10
```

I have omitted multiple lines that are not significant at the 0.05 level or below in the output (denoted by ...) for brevity.

The residual plots for this model are shown below:
[image: Second interaction model residuals]

The R-squared value is greatly improved (0.437 versus 0.076) but still nowhere close to what I think I need for a good model (R-squared > 0.8).

I am unsure of how to proceed - what to try next in order to get a better model.

Comment: Estimating around 250 parameters using only 999 lines does not look very promising. That is why the corresponding R-squared adjusted is so low.

Comment: Short of 'getting more data', if there anything I can do with what I have?

Comment: Sure there is. But your example neatly shows the need of having a modelling strategy at hand (depending on the purpose of your analysis, e.g it could be hypothesis testing, prediction or effect estimation, etc). To answer your question, we would need to write a whole book. Or simply refer to an excellent ressource like Frank Harrell's "Regression Modeling Strategies".